# How to find control with in repeater on button click event and repeater is placed with in gridview in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview, repeater

I need to check wheather the radionbutton is checked Or NOT then need to have its value to a variable .

How can i loop through the radioButtonList in repeater to check that user choose True or false  on button click and button is placed outside the gridview and repeater.

I tried this:
 protected void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsValid)
                return;
            int tcounter = 0;
            int fcounter = 0;

```
        for (int i = 0; i < gridMainSurveyQuestion.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            GridView grid = (GridView)gridMainSurveyQuestion.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions");

            Repeater repea = (Repeater)grid.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions");
            for (int j = 0; j < repea.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                RepeaterItem currentitem = repea.Items[j];
                RadioButtonList rlist = (RadioButtonList)currentitem.FindControl("rblanswer");
                if (rlist.SelectedItem.Value == "0")
                {
                    fcounter++;
                    lblfalse.Text = fcounter.ToString();
                }
                if (rlist.SelectedItem.Value == "1")
                {
                    tcounter++;
                    lbltrue.Text = tcounter.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but shows error:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView'.

Source Error:

Line 89:             for (int i = 0; i < gridMainSurveyQuestion.Rows.Count; i++)
Line 90:             {
Line 91: GridView grid = (GridView)gridMainSurveyQuestion.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions"); Line 92: 
Line 93:                 Repeater repea = (Repeater)grid.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions");

Source File: C:\Users\madiha.rahman\Desktop\PICG_SurveyModule\PICG_SurveyModule\Survey.aspx.cs    Line: 91

can you correct it

Comment: Remove this line from your code _GridView grid = (GridView)gridMainSurveyQuestion.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions");_.

Comment: Also edit your line _Repeater repea = (Repeater)grid.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions");_ **to** _Repeater repea = (Repeater)gridMainSurveyQuestion.Rows[i].FindControl("RptQuestions");_

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to iterate through GridView Rows for finding each repeater. Then from each repeater find each radiobuttonlist, like shown below.

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvTemp.Rows)
        {
            Repeater repeater = (Repeater)gvRow.FindControl("repeater1");

            foreach (RepeaterItem repItem in repeater.Items)
            {
                RadioButtonList rbList = (RadioButtonList)repItem.FindControl("radiobuttonlist1");

                foreach (ListItem item in rbList.Items)
                {
                    if (item.Selected)
                    {
                        //code for selected items goes here...
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //code for not selected items goes here...
                    }

                    if (item.Value == "0")
                    { 
                        //code for items with value == "0" goes here...
                    }

                    if (item.Value == "1")
                    {
                        //code for items with value == "1" goes here...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Happy Coding...;)

**EDIT :** Removed the checkbox & placed radiobuttonlist as required by the questioner.

**EDIT :** Added inner foreach loop that iterates through each radiobutton in the radiobuttonlist, as requested by the Questioner.

Comment: I need to find radiobuttonlist and need to count selected and un-selected radiobuttons

Comment: I have changed the code as per your requirement. For the error see my comments on your question. Accept as answer if this helps you.

Comment: It return number of o =false and 1=true  only ,I need to have number of unselected once also and had paging in gridview,do i need to do something for that ?

Comment: I have edited my answer and added a inner foreachloop for iterating through listitems in radiobuttonlist

Comment: Please, mark the answer as Accepted answer if it fulfills your requirement.